# i have to bucket each column in a dataframe (8 quintile)

Tags: python, dataframe, bucket

i have a dataframe which contains 4 columns, for each column we have to do bucketing (distribute data in 8 buckets) in such a way that bucketing should be done for first column and second column and so on iteratively without specifying the column name manually

this is the code i am trying

```
for col in df3.columns[0:]:
cb1 = np.linspace(min(col), max(col), 11)
df3.insert(2 ,'buckets',pd.cut(col, cb1, labels=np.arange(1, 11, 1)))
print(df3[col])
```

here df3 is the sample dataset

apple   orange  banana

5   2   6

6   4   6

2   8   9

4   7   0

the expected output is

apple   orange  banana  bucket_apple    bucket_orange   bucket_banana

5   2   6   1   3   2

6   4   6   1   1   4

2   8   9   2   1   8

4   7   0   5   4   1

here the bucket column is specifying the bucket number with respect to data

Comment: how do you decide which data go into what buckets? randomly?

Comment: my bucketing should be done based on the range of data, the total range of data should be cut into 8 equal buckets and whichever data falls into that bucket should be numbered accordingly. this has to do done for all columns in the dataframe @RockyLi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the output is totally random, there's no correlation between your data columns and the bucket nums, you should generate the buckets separately in that case.

```
for c in df.columns:
    df['bucket_' + c] = np.random.randint(8, size=(len(df))) + 1
df # your random bucket df.
```

If you want the bucket to become equal size:

```
for c in df.columns:
    arr = np.arange(8) + 1
    arr = np.repeat(arr, int(len(df))/8) # your df has to be divisible by 8
    np.random.shuffle(arr) # shuffle the array.
    df['bucket_' + c] = arr
```

Comment: I want my bucket number assigned according to the range (data should be divided into eight equal parts) for example 1-10 in bucket number 1, 10-20 in bucket number 2 and so on